# Class PDO not found when calling a singleton class

Tags: php, static, pdo, singleton

can anyone tell me what could cause this error "Fatal error: Class PDO not found"

when I call the singleton class like this: `$db = db::krijgInstantie();`

I use an mvc design and this error is weird, because I use the same code for another site

```
public static function krijgInstantie()
    {
        if (!self::$instantie)
        {
            $config = config::krijgInstantie();
            $db_type = $config->config_waarden['database']['db_type'];
            $hostnaam = $config->config_waarden['database']['db_hostnaam'];
            $dbnaam = $config->config_waarden['database']['db_naam'];
            $db_wachtwoord = $config->config_waarden['database']['db_wachtwoord'];
            $db_gebruikersnaam = $config->config_waarden['database']['db_gebruikersnaam'];
            $db_poort = $config->config_waarden['database']['db_poort'];

        self::$instantie = new PDO("$db_type:host=$hostnaam;port=$db_poort;dbname=$dbnaam",$db_gebruikersnaam, $db_wachtwoord);
            self::$instantie-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        return self::$instantie;
    }
```

thanks, Richard

Comment: Can you try `<?php echo (class_exists('PDO') === TRUE ? 'Yes' : 'No'); ?>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+Fatal+error%3A+Class+PDO+not+found

Comment: just a sec, NO, it says, I can't believe it..what could besetting this off, because I have multiple sites running in the same shared hosting environment---thank you @Mike--was hoping to be unique

Comment: @Richard In final words, PDO isn't installed OR enabled for this user. Are you using custom PHP.ini for each user ?

Comment: I don't use ini's at all, don't really no about them?must be the hoster that did something-it was working fine before

Comment: @Richard Do you have access to a custom PHP.ini or something ? Are you using cPanel or Directadmin or a different web panel ? What kind of hosting do you have.

Comment: shared hosting with cpanel..can I do something there? the hoster is company is closed now, so I can't call them about it

Comment: Check http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=680039, or contact your webhoster because if you are on a shared server, you may not be able to edit PHP.ini ... you need to enable two extensions : `pdo.so` and `pdo_mysql.so`

Comment: thank you, it will have to wait till tomorrow then, thanks for the input...I never really get what to do with these posts, it will stay open because I only got comments?

Comment: Yes, I can write an answer below or you can check as answered Brad's answer if youwant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP installation is missing the PDO module.  Check your PHP.ini.

See also:  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Comment: I will mark this one as the solution then, I call the hoster tomorrow! - and I will stop chatting stackoverflow!